# How to calculate the following product?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, products

How can we compute

$$\prod_{i=n}^{1}\cos^{2}\left(\frac{2^{i}}{2^{n+1}}x\right)$$

for $0<x<\pi$ ?

**Attempt:**

$$
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=n}^{1}\cos^{2}\left(\frac{2^{i}}{2^{n+1}}x\right) & =\prod_{i=n}^{1}\cos^{2}\left(\frac{2^{i}}{2^{n+1}}x\right)\\
 & =\prod_{i=n}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos\left(\frac{2^{i}}{2^{n}}x\right)\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{2^{n}}\prod_{i=n}^{1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin\left(2^{i+1-n}x\right)}{\sin\left(2^{i-n}x\right)}\right)\\
 & =?
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Hint $$\cos x=\dfrac{\sin2x}{2\sin x}$$

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I tried it but got stuck...

Comment: @robjohn There's not much context. It's not homework, it's just a calculation I tried to do but I can't.

Comment: It must be $\Pi^n_{i=1}$.

Comment: @sirous Isn't that the same?

Comment: No, it is not the same. Assuming $n\in\mathbb N$ you would have the empty product for $n>1$ which is defined to be $1$ and for $n=1$ you only have one factor and you could easily calculate the "product".

Comment: @Bella: use lab's hint which changes $\cos\left(\frac{2^ix}{2^{n+1}}\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2^{i+1}x}{2^{n+1}}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{2^ix}{2^{n+1}}\right)}$ . Now telescope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mbox{Note that} &
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\prod_{i = n}^{1}
\cos^{2}\pars{{2^{i} \over 2^{n + 1}}x}} =
\prod_{i = 1}^{n}
\cos^{2}\pars{{2^{i} \over 2^{n + 1}}x}
\\[5mm] & = 
\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\cos^{2}\pars{{2^{n + 1 - i} \over 2^{n + 1}}x}
=
\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\cos^{2}\pars{x \over 2^{i}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\cos\pars{x \over 2^{i}}}^{2}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

Moreover,
\begin{align}
\sin\pars{x} & = 2\sin\pars{x \over 2}\cos\pars{x \over 2} =
2^{2}\sin\pars{x \over 4}\cos\pars{x \over 4}\cos\pars{x \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
2^{3}\sin\pars{x \over 2^{3}}\cos\pars{x \over 2^{3}}
\cos\pars{x \over 2^{2}}\cos\pars{x \over 2^{1}}
\\[5mm] & = \cdots =
2^{n}\sin\pars{x \over 2^{n}}\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\cos\pars{x \over 2^{i}}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} lead to

$$
\bbx{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\prod_{i = n}^{1}\cos^{2}\pars{{2^{i} \over 2^{n + 1}}x}} =
{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over 2^{2n}\,\sin^{2}\pars{x/2^{n}}}}
$$

Comment: I just don't understand the very first step, on (1). Could you clarify why it is like that?

Comment: @Bella This property: $\displaystyle\prod_{i = m}^{n}f_{i} =  \prod_{i = m}^{n}f_{m + n - i}$. It is like $\displaystyle f_{1}f_{2}f_{3} = f_{3}f_{2}f_{1}$, etc$\displaystyle\ldots$.

Comment: I still don't get it. In this comment you don't change the ordering of $m$ and $n$ as you did above.

Comment: Let me put the question another way. If my original question had defined $\prod_{i=1}^{n}$ instead of $\prod_{i=n}^{1}$, with the same expression inside, what would change?

Comment: @Bella From $\displaystyle i$ to $\displaystyle  n$ or from $\displaystyle n$ to $\displaystyle  i$ the result will be the same ( "Order of the factors doesn't change the product" ).

Comment: @Bella $\displaystyle \prod_{i = n}^{1}a_{i} = \prod_{i = 1}^{n}a_{i}$ or, in another words,  $\displaystyle a_{n}a_{n - 1}\ldots a_{2}a_{1} = a_{1}a_{2}\ldots a_{n - 1}a_{n}$